# Rive animation is not working on flutter web with Firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, rive

I have added Rive animation to my flutter project under assets/rive/ (https://prnt.sc/d2qorEjp1itB) but when I deploy the app on firebase hosting its not working. Working on local host.

I was looking for a solution and find that the possible issue can be assets path. Like in my flutter code I use it like this `rive/solar.riv`

```
SizedBox(

width: 600 * screenWidth,
height: 600 * screenHeight,
child: const Hero(
       tag: 'solar',
       child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                   'rive/solar.riv',
                    artboard: 'Planets',
                    stateMachines: ['PlanetsStat'],
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
 ),
),
```

But they suggest to add assets before the path. I did it too. But not working.